# How can I make HTML/CSS changes automatically reload in the browser under Windows?

Tags: windows, firefox

I am making changes in HTML/CSS. They should be auto-refreshed/shown in my Firefox browser.

Do I need a special editor for this? If not, how can I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the LiveReload app

An app / plugin that does this is [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/).

> LiveReload monitors changes in the file system. As soon as you save a file, it is preprocessed as needed, and the browser is refreshed. Even cooler, when you change a CSS file or an image, the browser is updated instantly without reloading the page.

However, that app / plugin has not been updated in a while.

---

#### Using `grunt` and a live reload server

What you could do instead is to run a server, such as [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/), and a plugin that watches for file changes, like [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch). The server injects JavaScript into your HTML page so that changes in the watched files trigger a reload of the website.

First, install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then, from the command-line, go to your project folder (where the HTML files are) and run:

```
npm install grunt grunt-contrib-watch grunt-contrib-connect --save-dev
```

Create a file called `Gruntfile.js` and add the following contents:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
      watch: {
        files: ['**/*'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
      },
      connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                  livereload: true,
                }
          }
      }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:server', 'watch']);
};
```

Save it and run the following command:

```
grunt
```

Now navigate to `http://localhost:8000/` — the assets will trigger a reload of your HTML when they are changed.

Have a look at the [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/) and [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/) documentation for more configuration options.

Comment: This stopped working at the release of Firefox 57, as this release does not support legacy extensions which LiveReload still is, unfortunately :(.

Comment: @ErikWestrup I guess that this LiveReload project is dead, but more modern alternatives like live-reloading servers exist. I updated my answer to give a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Another program is [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), which reflects edits the moment they are made ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nhvj1NYC3Uc)), but it probably supports only Chrome for now.

Comment: tried that already, its not that good, you have to create a whole project inside it , and create a new css files too inside it.

Answer (score 1):

**[This Firefox addon monitors CSS files for changes and reloads the file without reloading the HTML when the CSS file is changed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-reload/)**. This addon does not require plugins for your editor.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm the author of this addon and I created it specifically to solve the the same problem OP was having.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If using editor VS Code, there is a plugin: Live Server(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) does have live reload feature. It will reload page change automatically in browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you are editing your file in notepad++, just press cntrl S to save after your changes.

### Download the firefox extension for auto refresh

(there are many available) and **set the timer to 1 second.**

Now whenever you press cntrl S to save your changes the web browser, refreshing at whichever interval you have set, will also reload your last saved changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your `gulp.js` file

check this repo https://github.com/Anasmp/html-debugger-realtime

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    bs.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", bs.reload);
    gulp.watch("src/*.css").on("change", bs.reload);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would be surprised if this is possible.  Auto-refreshing would typically be done with HTML or Javascript code in the HTML file, rather then any editor.

Comment: "Live Refresh" as the OP calls it is probably [Live Reload](http://livereload.com/). Editors can "push" a notification to the browser to update a page. See also: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Firefox getting refreshed automatically does not have to do with HTML editor.

if you use adobe Dreamweaver which is a WYSIWYG(What You See Is What You Get) program for making webpages.you can see the result of HTML code you are writing in the design window in the program. without needing to refresh the window.

Comment: Not entirely true. See my answer—there's a framework that does *exactly* that: letting Firefox (or any browser) listen to changes in files. No WYSIWYG needed because the browser becomes the preview window.